# Conditional test in JSON model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, if-statement, model

I need to know how to add conditional if test in rails method when define a json object :

```
def save_metadata
    if model.class == Medium && file.present? && file.content_type.end_with?( 'jpeg' )
      exif_info = EXIFR::JPEG.new( url_or_path )
      if exif_info.gps.nil?
        model.metadata = {
          width:              exif_info.width,
          height:             exif_info.height,
          image_width:        exif_info.image_width,
          image_length:       exif_info.image_length,
          if exif_info.date_time.utc?
          date_time_original: exif_info.date_time.utc
        }
      else
        model.metadata = {
          width:              exif_info.width,
          height:             exif_info.height,
          make:               exif_info.make,
          model:              exif_info.model,
          date_time_original: exif_info.date_time.utc,
          image_width:        exif_info.image_width,
          image_length:       exif_info.image_length,
          gps_latitude:       exif_info.gps.latitude,
          gps_longitude:      exif_info.gps.longitude,
          gps_date_stamp:     format_date( exif_info ),
          gps_time_stamp:     format_date_time( exif_info )
        }
      end
      model.save!
    end
  end
```

I want to test if the **exif_info.date_time.utc** is not nil, i got this error :

> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
>               date_time_original: exif_info.date_time.utc

Comment: you're writing if end condition in the hash ?

Comment: it's not possible ?

Comment: check my answer, if you want to add a key with value in your hash if it is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can merge the key `date_time_original` with value in your hash `model.metadata`

```
model.metadata = {
  width:              exif_info.width,
  height:             exif_info.height,
  image_width:        exif_info.image_width,
  image_length:       exif_info.image_length
}

model.metadata.merge!({date_time_original: exif_info.date_time.utc}) if exif_info.date_time.utc?
```

you can edit the condition as per your requirement

more on [merge!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!)

Comment: Yes it will, you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because you have an `if` condition while building a `Hash`. You can do it after you have the hash. You can set the value of a key in hash conditionally as below:

```
if exif_info.gps.nil?
  model.metadata = {
                     width:        exif_info.width,
                     height:       exif_info.height,
                     image_width:  exif_info.image_width,
                     image_length: exif_info.image_length,
                   }
  model.metadata[:date_time_original] = exif_info.date_time.utc if exif_info.date_time.utc?
else
  model.metadata = {
                     width:              exif_info.width,
                     height:             exif_info.height,
                     make:               exif_info.make,
                     model:              exif_info.model,
                     date_time_original: exif_info.date_time.utc,
                     image_width:        exif_info.image_width,
                     image_length:       exif_info.image_length,
                     gps_latitude:       exif_info.gps.latitude,
                     gps_longitude:      exif_info.gps.longitude,
                     gps_date_stamp:     format_date( exif_info ),
                     gps_time_stamp:     format_date_time( exif_info )
                   }
end
```